# Create class diagrams from C# code (either visual or plan text is fine)

Tags: c#, diagram

I do not need necessarily to get UML diagrams; all that I am trying to get, is something that I can print on paper and look at, while I write code.

At the moment my code base is getting big, and I have to load files in the editor, to look at what the code does; and where a specific method live. This slow me down quite a lot; and I am not at the point where I can just create the whole thing by hand.

Is there a way to create a list of classes, the methods for each class, and output it in a nice way? I have Visual Studio; and I did try the "class diagram" option; but it is horrible and useless to me.

Is there any trick that I can employ via code, so I can write something that parse the code for each class that I pass, and output it in a nice way? I did someting similar in the past using shell scripting; which could be a viable option after all.

I would love something visual as output, but even text is fine; I can draw by hands the nice boxes. Any script out there that does this, or do I have to write my own parser?

Comment: is class diagram enough for you?

Comment: in VS, click View -> Class View, you will get all the class available per project. Then select a class or multiple class and right click select View Class Diagram.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply; but I did mention that I did try already "class diagram". That won't work for me, since I don't get details that I need from that output.

Comment: Can you explain why the `class diagram` from Visual Studio is "useless and horrible" to you? Because it creates a list of classes (which you can arrange as you like it) and the methods for each class (expand/collapse able) and the output is visual as you'd love it.

Comment: Sure, I was not clear with my statement. Basically it won't tell you returned values from a function or method, their signatures and such. It does create a list of methods for each class, and relations (parent/child, from what I can see), but to me is important also see the signatures; so when I write a new class or method, I can see how to interact with such classes, before even import them. I saw time ago, more descriptive diagrams; but I am not sure if they were created by hand or through a script/code introspection